# Is there a "natural" norm in the space of all sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $X$ be $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, the space of all real-valued sequences. Is there a natural norm in this space?

Comment: I imagine you want the norm to induce the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: What does "natural norm" mean? But the answer is most likely "No", in the product topology it is a Fréchet space which isn't locally bounded.

Comment: Moreover, thanks to the open mapping theorem for Fréchet spaces, there is no norm inducing a topology which is either strictly weaker or strictly stronger than the product topology.  In particular, there is no norm which will make all the projection functionals continuous.

Comment: @NateEldredge No norm which makes the space complete can be comparable. The open mapping theorem doesn't guarantee that a norm in which the space is incomplete isn't comparable. I tend to believe there is none for this space, but I have no idea how to prove that.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Thanks! The comments by Daniel Fischer and Nate Eldredge answer my question.